# How to download Code.org's Courses

Tags: download, website

We want to implement the code.org's curriculum into our school system and teach K-12 grades CS.
But we can not afford high speed internet for each student to access the courses online.
How can we download the course so that the students can access them offline ?
I've tried the website copying programs, but they don't work since the links are server-side and programs can't catch them.
How can I download them?

Comment: A proxy server https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server  such as Squid http://www.squid-cache.org/ may do the job, if you have adequate technical expertise or can hire it. However, make sure to ask for their consent! https://support.code.org/hc/en-us/requests/new

Answer (score 3):

#### How can I download them?

You can't (legally) as it forbidden by their Terms of Service unless there is a download link provided:

> Code.org’s library of videos may be redistributed freely on the express conditions that (1) the videos are redistributed AS-IS in their entirety, using the embedded video player provided, or by downloading the original video file IF a download link is provided, and with clear attribution to Code.org

Source [Terms of Service | Code.org](https://code.org/tos)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest getting in touch with the code.org administrators,
explain your problem and ask for their help.

You may start in the [Submit a request page](https://support.code.org/hc/en-us/requests/new).

If you present yourself well-enough and the number of courses is relatively modest,
they might cooperate.

Comment: Why downvote a practical advice?